# Link to div scrolls to a wrong position

Tags: html, url, scroll, anchor, adsense

On an article page, there are user comments which are marked with div id.

```
<div id="comment1234">
    Comment
</div>
```

Users get a notification when the comment has been approved with the URL.

```
https://mywebsite.com/article2/#comment1234
```

The problem is the scrolling behaviour. The browser scrolls to the "random" position, not to the div. I expect this is caused by dynamically added Adsense auto-ads. How could this be fixed?

Comment: Could you please provide code example? So it's not clear for now.

Comment: @Vetos thanks for the comment. I was a little unclear, there is no code. This is the browser's standard functionality. When I link to https://example.com/page#elementName, the browser should scroll to that element. And it does, but it scrolls often to a wrong position. I guess the reason is that the auto-ads are being dynamically injected into the content.

Comment: It can't be wrong. That is why I asked you for a code example or maybe even screenshots of this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share a screenshot. I am 98 percent sure that the issue is injected ads. The browser calculates the scroll position before the ads are injected. It will result wrong scrolling. Still wondering, what could be a workaround.

Comment: You can't even provide a screenshot of page? How could I help you ^_^

Comment: @vetos. If you know a workaround, I am happy to get help from you. Is there something I could clarify more? Just ask me. :)

Comment: After some debugging, the problem is an iframe whose height is initially unknown. The scrolling position is calculated before the iframe's content comes visible, so the scrolling position is wrong. It should be the calculated position plus iframe's height.

Comment: Probably, I will implement Javascript code that  "re-scrolls" to the correct 0.5s after the page load. It will fix the majority of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems the solve the challenge:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    setTimeout(() => { 
        let tag = $($(location).attr('hash'));
        let marginTop = 90; 
        if (tag.offset() != false) 
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: tag.offset().top-marginTop},'slow');
    }, 800);
});
```

It will re-scroll to the correct position 800ms after the page load.